# nls sslogis: using a dummy variable as an interaction term to compare two sigmoid models

Tags: r, nls, dummy-variable, sigmoid, asymptote

I use the following model in my code:

```
model <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), 
   data = data.frame(x, y))
```

There is a variable (`V`) with two levels: `V1` and `V2`

- Model 1: Fitting Y to X with a sigmoid function when V=V1 --> asymptote1
- Model 2: Fitting Y to X with a sigmoid function when V=V2 --> asymptote2

Where `asymptote1` and `asymptote2` are not equal.

How can we show that the asymptotes are significantly different?

Is there any way to use `V` as an interaction term and get the interaction coefficient? I introduces V-Dummy in the model and it generates the following error:

> Error in (attr(object, "initial"))(mCall = mCall, data = data, LHS = LHS) : 
>     too few distinct input values to fit a logistic model

If not, what do you suggest as an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use `nlme::gnls`:

```
model <- gnls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), 
              data = data.frame(x, y),
              params = list(Asym ~ V))
```

By default, this will return two parameters for `Asym`: one for the baseline level (`V1` by default) and one for the difference in asymptotes between V1 and V2.  `summary()` should include all of the usual inferential information (std error, p-value, etc.)

From `?nlme::gnls`:

> params: an optional two-sided linear formula of the form
>             ‘p1+...+pn~x1+...+xm’, or list of two-sided formulas of the
>             form ‘p1~x1+...+xm’, with possibly different models for each
>             parameter. The ‘p1,...,pn’ represent parameters included on
>             the right hand side of ‘model’ and ‘x1+...+xm’ define a
>             linear model for the parameters (when the left hand side of
>             the formula contains several parameters, they are all assumed
>             to follow the same linear model described by the right hand
>             side expression). A ‘1’ on the right hand side of the
>             formula(s) indicates a single fixed effects for the
>             corresponding parameter(s). By default, the parameters are
>             obtained from the names of ‘start’.